# Trennt man "die man schläft" mit Kommas/Beistrichen ab?

Tags: punctuation, comma

Gehören in den folgenden beiden Sätze Kommas/Beistriche?
Wenn ja: Warum?
Wenn nein: Warum nicht?

> Jede Stunde die man schläft nimmt man 42 g ab.
>   In jeder Stunde die man schläft nimmt man 42 g ab.

Ich vermute, dass beide Sätze, so wie sie da stehen, richtig sind. Ich glaube also, dass kein Komma hineingehört.

Falls aber doch, müsste man vermutlich gleich zwei Beistriche setzen, nämlich nach »Stunde« und »schläft«. Ich bin mir da aber höchst unsicher. Mir ist nämlich nicht klar, welche grammatikalische Funktion die Wortfolge »die man schläft« in den beiden Sätzen hat.

Comment: Dass Kommas gesetzt werden müssen, sieht man am besten daran, dass zwei konjugierte/finite Verbformen auftreten (...schläft..., ...nimmt...), die jeweils ihr eigenes Subjekt haben (beide Male "man").

Comment: @Chris: Ah, super! Das ist eine schlüssige und leicht zu merkende Erklärung! Danke!

Comment: Deutsch ist doch deine Muttersprache?! Ehrlich gesagt verstehe ich nicht, wie du zu der Annahme kommst, dass da kein Komma hinsollte. Dass "die" ein Relativpronomen ist, das sich auf Stunde bezieht, ist offensichtlich. Und ein Relativsatz wird im Deutschen immer mit einem Komma abgetrennt.

Comment: Dass man bei Relativsätzen Beistriche setzt ist mir schon klar. Mir war unklar, dass »die man schläft« ein Relativsatz ist. Meine Muttersprache ist zwar deutsch, aber ich habe eigentlich nie wirklich die dazugehörige Theorie, also die Rechtschreibregeln, gelernt, weil ich vom Beginn der Volksschule bis zur Matura immer nur ganz besonders un-engagierte Deutschlehrer hatte denen egal war ob wir etwas lernen. Ich hatte als Schüler auch eher Interesse an Mathematik und Physik als an Sprachen. Für die Deutsche Sprache begann ich mich erst vor ca. 10 Jahren (also mit rund 40) zu interessieren.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Wahrscheinlich würdest Du es bei aufmerksamem Lesen selbst bemerken, aber da es erstens genau zur Frage passt und ich zweitens in Gönnerlaune bin: *Dass man bei Relativsätzen Beistriche setzt***,** *ist mir schon klar.* und *weil ich (...) Deutschlehrer hatte***,** *denen egal war***,** *ob wir etwas lernen.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Es handelt sich in beiden Fällen um einen eingeschobenen Nebensatz, der (so wie du vermutest) von Kommas eingeschlossen werden muß. Im amtlichen Regelwerk ist das in [§74](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf71-79.html#pgf74) festgehalten, der im Duden als [Kommaregel 121](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K121) wiedergegeben wird.

Answer (score 6):

Die Antwort ist ein ganz klares "ja". Bei beiden Beispielen handelt es sich um ganz normale Relativsätze, die immer durch Kommata abgetrennt werden.

Comment: Ja, [Beistrich](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Beistrich) ist in der Tat ein Synonym für *Komma*, das bei uns in Österreich sehr gebräuchlich ist.

Comment: Was heißt "Kommi"? Meinst du vielleicht *Kommata* oder *Kommas*? Beides sind mögliche Pluralformen von *Komma*.

Comment: Und ich weiß nicht was »Kommi« sind. ;) Bei uns in Österreich sagt man »Beistriche«, »Kommas« oder »Kommata«. In Österreich wird das Wort »Komma« verwendet wenn damit das Dezimaltrennzeichen in einer Zahl gemeint ist (4,5 = vier Komma fünf). Als Satzzeichen ist aber die Bezeichnung »Beistrich« gebräuchlich (vor ca. 30 Jahren ausschließlich, heute gleich häufig wie »Komma«). Mir war gar nicht bewusst, dass man das Wort »Beistrich« in Deutschland nicht kennt.

Comment: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komma *"Das Komma (Pl. Kommas oder Kommata; auch: der Beistrich) ist ein Satzzeichen und in vielen Ländern das Dezimaltrennzeichen."*

Comment: @HubertSchölnast... ah gut zu wissen. Ich hatte das Wort tatsächlich noch nie gehört und habe spontan eher an BIndestrich gedacht. Kommi war eine Übersprungshandlung, da ich mich nicht zwischen Kommas und Kommata entscheiden konnte ;)