# (kurzer) Nebensatz im Nebensatz: Kommas optional?

Tags: spelling, punctuation, comma, subordinate-clause

In einer Antwort zu einer [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15405/trennt-man-die-man-schl%C3%A4ft-mit-kommas-beistriche-ab), in der es ironischerweise um Kommasetzung bei eingeschobenen Nebensätzen ging, schrieb ich:

> Es handelt sich in beiden Fällen um einen eingeschobenen Nebensatz, der so wie du vermutest von Kommas eingeschlossen werden muß.

[Em1](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/1224/em1) merkte dazu an, dass »so wie Du vermutest« ebenfalls durch Kommas (oder hilfsweise Gedankenstriche) abgetrennt werden müsse, also

> Es handelt sich in beiden Fällen um einen eingeschobenen Nebensatz, der, so wie du vermutest, von Kommas eingeschlossen werden muß.

oder

> Es handelt sich in beiden Fällen um einen eingeschobenen Nebensatz, der – so wie du vermutest – von Kommas eingeschlossen werden muß.

Mir missfällt bei beiden Varianten die Sprechpause, die die Zeichensetzung suggeriert. Ich würde den kompletten Nebensatz ab *der* ohne Pause in einem Atem sprechen. Die Variante mit Komma sieht obendrein durch das alleinstehende *der* zerstückelt aus. Ich hatte deswegen gehofft (aber in der Eile nicht nachgeschlagen), dass diese Kommas optional sind.

Soweit ich bislang sehe, hat Em1 aber Recht und ich keine Wahl. Meine **Frage**: Ist dem wirklich so, oder gibt es eine Klausel, auf die ich mich berufen könnte, um die beiden Kommas wegzulassen?

Bislang habe ich die [Regel 125](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K125) des Dudens gefunden – formelhafter Gebrauch eines verkürzten Nebensatzes. Diese würde nach meiner Interpretation (leider) nicht auf meinen Satz zutreffen, jedoch auf

> ..., der wie vermutet von Kommas eingeschlossen werden muß.

was ich aber stilistisch nicht überzeugend finde.

Comment: Ich denke, dass dir keine Wahl bleibt. – Nebenbei, ich mache dort eine Sprechpause und betone "so".

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13752/kommasetzung-bei-nur-wenn

Comment: Anders als im Englischen korrelieren Kommata im Deutschen eher zufällig mit Sprechpausen. Klammern wären auch möglich, da es sich um einen optionalen Teilsatz handelt.

Comment: @Crissov Stimmt, Klammern wären noch eine Alternative. Unterbrechen für mein Gefühl an der Stelle den Sprachfluß sogar weniger als die Gedankenstriche. Aber hinsichtlich der Sprechpausen kann ich nur widersprechen. Lies doch mal nur den ersten Satz von http://www.nordcomp.de/northsail/seiten/thomas_mann.htm . Bei welchem Komma machst Du keine Pause, und wo machst Du eine Pause, an der kein Komma steht? Wenn das Zufall sein soll, wünschte ich mir eine ähnlich zufällige Korrelation der Lottozahlen mit meinem Tippschein ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

§ 76 der Rechtschreibregeln lautet:

> Bei formelhaften Nebensätzen kann man das Komma weglassen.
>
> *Wie bereits gesagt(,) verhält sich die Sache anders. Ich komme(,) wenn
>   nötig(,) bei dir noch vorbei.*

Auch wenn beide Beispiele verkürzt sind, steht nichts dergleichen in der Regel – das ist auf dem Mist des Dudens gewachsen.

Ich persönlich empfinde Dein Beispiel zwar nicht als einen solchen formelhaften Nebensatz, aber würde es auch nicht als klar falsch ansehen. Und da meine Meinung eben nur diese ist und die Regel schwammig ist, kannst Du Dich auf jeden Fall darauf berufen.

Dass Du die Kommata nicht durch eine Pause oder Ähnliches betonst, ist ein Indiz dafür ist, dass Du den Nebensatz nicht mehr als solchen wahrnimmst, sondern nur als eine Aneinanderreihung von Worten mit einer gewissen Bedeutung, die auf einen Nebensatz zurückgeht – was für die Formelhaftigkeit des Nebensatzes spricht. Wie bereits gesagt kommt mir das bei Deinem Beispiel etwas ungewöhnlich vor, da der Satz recht spezifisch ist und z. B. davon abhängt, wer etwas vermutet; ganz im Gegensatz zu folgendem Beispiel:

> Es handelt sich in beiden Fällen um einen eingeschobenen Nebensatz, der wie vermutet von Kommas eingeschlossen werden muss.

Comment: Danke für die ausgewogene und differenzierte Antwort. Besonderer Aha-Effekt war für mich der Hinweis, daß der Duden hier nicht dasselbe sagt wie die amtliche Version der Regeln. Vielleicht wollten sie einfach nur helfend interpretieren, aber der historisch bedingte Status des Dudens ließ dies für mich wie die Regel selbst aussehen. - Bei der Gelegenheit: eine soweit ich sehe unveränderte, aber besser als das Original-PDF handhabbare (insbesondere verlinkbare) Online-Version der amtlichen Regeln findet man hier: http://canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Diese Frage ist aus dem Standpunkt heraus gestellt, dass die Rechtschreib- und Grammatikregeln diktieren, wie deutsche Sprache zu verschriftlichen ist. Das ist ein Standpunkt, der in der akademischen Behandlung der Sprache, vor allem aber in der Lehre, durchaus seine Berechtigung hat.

Es gibt aber auch einen anderen Standpunkt:

Das Formulieren der Rechtschreib- und Grammatikregeln ist dazu da, häufige Zusammenhänge, die man in geschriebenen Texten findet, unabhängig von den konkreten Einzeltexten zu machen und somit zu abstrahieren. Man will also aus dem verfügbaren Schriftgut, das idealerweise frei von Regeln entstanden ist, ein allgemein gültiges Regelwerk herausdestillieren. Der Zweck dieses Regelwerks ist dann wiederum die Lehre, damit erreicht wird, dass Leser im ganzem deutschen Sprachraum Texte lesen können, die nach gleichen Regeln gegliedert und notiert sind.

Wie man es also dreht und wendet, es geht um Vereinheitlichung und um eine Möglichkeit diese Einheitlichkeit zu beschreiben und zu vermitteln.

Der eigentliche Zweck von Sprache ist aber ein anderer: Sprache vermittelt Gedanken und Ideen. Die Sprache ist der gemeinsame Code, den Sender und Empfänger einer Nachricht verwenden, um diese Nachricht zu transportieren.

Wenn also der Empfänger problemlos dieselbe Nachricht versteht die der Sender formuliert hat, dann hat die Sprache ihren Zweck zu 100% erfüllt. Das Erfüllen von Rechtschreibregeln ist dann nur hübsches Beiwerk.

So gesehen ist es also völlig egal, ob man einen eingeschobenen Nebensatz, der, wie an diesem Beispiel hier, oder an diesem Nebensatz, der, man glaubt es kaum, noch tiefer verschachtelt ist, gezeigt wird, in einen anderen Nebensatz eingeschoben ist, vom umgebenden Satzgefüge durch Kommata trennt oder nicht.

So einen Satz wie den vorangegangenen muss man wenigstens dreimal lesen um ihn zu verstehen, obwohl er (hoffentlich) allen Regeln der Kunst entspricht. Kommata sind dann nur die Haltegriffe an denen man sich beim Abstieg in die Tiefe festhält, aber sie allein tragen nur wenig dazu bei den eigentlichen Zweck der Sprache - das Transportieren von Ideen - zu erfüllen.

Daher mein Standpunkt:
Wenn man einen Satz gleich beim ersten Lesen hundertprozentig versteht wurde er richtig geschrieben.

Angewendet auf die konkrete Frage: Wenn du meinst, dass Kommas helfen den Lesefluss zu verbessern, dann mach sie rein. Wenn du findest dass sie den Fluss eher behindern, dann lass sie weg.

(Mir ist klar, dass dieser Ratschlag dem offiziellen Regelwerk der deutschen Sprache widerspricht. Aber die Regeln sollen den tatsächlichen Gebrauch der Sprache wiederspiegelen, nicht umgekehrt)

Comment: Es ist mitnichten mein Standpunkt, dass die Rechtschreibregeln irgend etwas diktieren. Ein Indiz dafür habe ich sogar durch den Gebrauch des 'ß' in der Frage selbst geliefert (mittlerweile weg-editiert). Aber ich stimme Dir zu, dass ein Regelwerk dabei hilft, "dass Leser im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum Texte lesen können, die nach gleichen Regeln gegliedert und notiert sind", und halte das für sehr sinnvoll und hilfreich. Mit meiner Frage möchte ich letztlich verstehen, ob ich mich in dem Fall noch innerhalb des Regelwerks bewege oder (bewusst) daraus heraustrete.

Answer (score 0):

Grundsätzlich müssen eingeschobene Nebensätze eingeklammert werden.
Diesen Nebensatz nicht einzuklammern zerstört jedoch nicht den Fluss, daher kann man sie mMn weglassen.

Willst du aber die Vermutung der Person betonen, dann setze Beistriche/Kommas.