# Komma für vollständigen Satz im längeren Satz?

Tags: punctuation, comma

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> Peres war lange umstritten, erst im Alter, er ist heute 91, wurde er populär.

Ist die Verwendung von Kommas um "er ist heute 91" korrekt? Dieser Fall ist anders als der [in dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15414/kurzer-nebensatz-im-nebensatz-kommas-optional), weil der Teil "er ist heute 91" kein Nebensatz, sondern ein vollständiger Satz ist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dem gegebenen Satz

> Erst im Alter, er ist heute 91, wurde er populär.

handelt es sich bei „er ist heute 91“ um eine **Parenthese,** also um einen Ausdruck, der außerhalb des eigentlichen Satzverbandes steht.

Gemäß § 77 (1) des Regelwerks zur deutschen Rechtschreibung grenzt man Parenthesen mit paarigem Komma ein.

> Eines Tages, es war mitten im Sommer, hagelte es.
> Dieses Bild, es ist das letzte und bekannteste des Künstlers, wurde nach Amerika verkauft.
> Ihre Forderung, um das noch einmal zu sagen, halten wir für wenig angemessen.

somit auch:

> Erst im Alter, er ist heute 91, wurde er populär.

Möglich sind gemäß § 84 (1) auch Gedankenstriche

> Eines Tages – es war mitten im Sommer – hagelte es.
> Eines Tages – es war mitten im Sommer! – hagelte es.
> Eines Tages – war es mitten im Sommer? – hagelte es.
> Dieses Bild – es ist das letzte und bekannteste des Künstlers – wurde nach Amerika verkauft.
> Ihre Forderung – um das noch einmal zu sagen – halten wir für wenig angemessen.
>
> Erst im Alter – er ist heute 91 – wurde er populär.

oder gemäß § 86 (1) Klammern.

> Eines Tages (es war mitten im Sommer) hagelte es.
> Eines Tages (es war mitten im Sommer!) hagelte es.
> Eines Tages (war es mitten im Sommer?) hagelte es.
> Dieses Bild (es ist das letzte und bekannteste des Künstlers) wurde nach Amerika verkauft.
> Ihre Forderung (um das noch einmal zu sagen) halten wir für wenig angemessen.
>
> Erst im Alter (er ist heute 91) wurde er populär.

Mit Gedankenstrichen oder Klammern kennzeichnet man stärker als mit Kommas, dass man etwas als Zusatz oder Nachtrag verstanden wissen will.

Answer (score 4):

Ja, ist richtig.

> Peres **war** lange umstritten.

... ist in diesem Fall ein Hauptsatz, Die Personalform steht an 2. Stelle (das Verb, das sich je nach Person ändert, ich war, du warst...)

> Erst im Alter **wurde** er populär.

... ist wieder ein Hauptsatz.

> Er **ist** heute 91.

... ist ein vollständiger Satz mit Subjekt und Personalform. Er ist zwar ein Hauptsatz und kein Gliedsatz, trotzdem MUSS man einen Beistrich setzen (so einen Fall nennt man **eingeschobener Hauptsatz**

Grundsätzlich gilt, alle Sätze mit einer Personalform müssen mit Beistrichen getrennt werden. Ein Satz kann nicht zwei Personalformen haben.

Comment: Natürlch wären auch andere Satzzeichen, insb. Punkte, Semikola, Gedankenstriche oder auch ein Doppelpunkt möglich. (zB.: Peres war lange umstritten; erst im Alter -- er ist heute 91 -- wurde er populär.)

Comment: @Iris: Kann es sein, dass du mit »Personalform« eigentlich »Subjekt« (»Satzgegenstand«) meinst? Ich kenne der Begriff »Personalform« sonst nur im Zusammenhang mit der Konjugation von Verben (»gehe«, »gehst« und »geht« sind drei Personalformen desselben Verbs, alle drei Singular Präsens)

Answer (score 3):

Was ein wenig komisch wirkt, sind die drei kurzaufeinanderfolgenden Kommas, die eine unterschiedliche Funktion ausüben. Das zweite und dritte Komma werden dazu verwendet, um den Einschub abzugrenzen, während das erste zwei semantisch getrennte Hauptsätze voneinander abhebt.
Der Einschub "er ist heute 91" muss definitiv abgegrenzt werden. Neben dem bereits vorgeschlagenen Dash kann man hier auch zu Klammern greifen.

> Peres war lange umstritten, erst im Alter (er ist heute 91) wurde er populär.

Vor allen Dingen würde ich aber auch dazu raten, nach dem ersten Teil entweder einen Punkt oder zumindest ein Semikolon zu setzen. In dem Fall schmerzen die nachfolgenden Kommas auch viel weniger.

> Peres war lange umstritten. Erst im Alter, er ist heute 91, wurde er populär.
>   Peres war lange umstritten; erst im Alter, er ist heute 91, wurde er populär.

Comment: Der Name des Satzzeichens, das du in der Antwort von Grantwalzer gesehen hast, heißt nicht »Dash«, sondern, wie Grantwalzer ganz richtig geschrieben hat, »Gedankenstrich«. Typographisch ist das ein Halbgeviertstrich, Grammatisch aber eben ein Gedankenstrich. »Dash« ist kein Begriff der deutschen Grammatik.

Answer (score 1):

Irgendeine Abgrenzung ist auf jeden Fall notwendig:

> Peres war lange umstritten, erst im Alter er ist heute 91 wurde er populär. *(autsch)*

Subjektiv schließt der eingeschobene Satz grammatikalisch jedoch nicht sehr flüssig an, sodass Gedankenstriche vielleicht eher angebracht wären:

> Peres war lange umstritten, erst im Alter – er ist heute 91 – wurde er populär.